# How to use a while loop to merge 2 arrays

Tags: java

I have given what I have of the program so far now I have to use a while-loop to traverse through BOTH arrays merging them into "merge" array such that merge is in ascending order. Rather than first.length & second.length, you should use countFirst & countSecond. That is, you should compare indexFirst to countFirst & compare indexSecond to countSecond
I am not sure how to do this so if can help me that will be great

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class MergeArrays {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        int [] first = new int [20];
        int countFirst = 0;      //used to determine number of elements in "first"

        int [] second = new int [20];
        int countSecond = 0;    //used to determine number of elements in "second"

        int [] merge = new int [40];

        int indexMerge = 0;
        int indexFirst = 0;
        int indexSecond = 0;

        //open files
        Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("array1.txt"));
        Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File("array2.txt"));
        //Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("array1b.txt"));
        //Scanner inFile2 = new Scanner(new File("array2b.txt"));

        while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
            first[countFirst] = inFile1.nextInt();
            countFirst++;
        }

        while (inFile1.hasNext()) {
            first[countFirst] = inFile1.nextInt();
            countFirst++;
        }

        indexFirst = 0;
        indexSecond = 0;
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe your second while loop should read in inFile2 to the second[] array. Have you tried anything for the actual merge? Try doing it by hand for two small arrays to get an idea how it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like homework, I'm not going to give the full answer, but.

What if you only used one loop, and during each iteration, you decided which array you wanted to add an element from, and you added a new element from that array.

you might be able to solve your problem with that approach.